# How to output PDOException error running CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.4, and I'm trying to use PDO instead of the internal database object.

I'd changed the "/config/database.php" to use pdo, and "/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_drivers.php" function db_connet(), pdo::attr_errmode to use pdo::errmode_exception mode instead of silent mode.

I ran my query like this:

```
try {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($query);

  $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {

  $e->getMessage();
}
```

The code works fine except it's not outputting any error if it occurs. I'd tested it without the try/catch block but it's still the same.

Comment: What do you get when you do a `var_dump($e)` inside your `catch()` block?

Comment: nothing, I entered random stuff into the query string and run it, and it gave me nothing.

Comment: Why do you want to run a query like this?

Comment: I want to find out why it's not displaying the error.